# Is it possible to do data-driven tests in Testcafe Studio

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is it possible to to feed data into a Testcafe Studio tests so the same test can be completed with different sets of data without having to record a new test each time?

Thanks.

Comment: I was wondering if you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible.

```js
[1, 2, 3].forEach(data => {
    test.only        
        ('Data Driven Example', async t => {

        console.log(data);     
    });
});
```

It will become useful when you have data in some separate file like so:

```js
const testData = require(`../Resources/${process.env.TESTCAFE_ENV}/logIn.json`);

testData.credentials.forEach(credentials => {
    test        
        ('Log Into User Account', async t => {

        await LogIn.logIn(credentials.username, credentials.password);

        await t
            .expect(PageMsg.pageMsg.innerText).eql(PageMsg.successfulLogIn)                  
            .expect(Selector(ProfileForm.inputObj.name.input).value).eql(credentials.name);        
    });
});
```

All this is mentioned in the official [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/best-practices/create-data-driven-tests.html).

**EDIT**: This is a valid way, but the question is more focused on TestCafe Studio and how to do it in it. Havind said that, my answer doesn't really answer that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply very much appreciated, I had seen this in the documentation, I was wondering if there is a non programmatic way to do this via studio?

Comment: I see, I actually missed that studio part in your question, my bad. Then my answer is not relevant. I don't even use the studio, so I'm afraid I can't be more of help here.